# How to recompile Google Drive API sdk?

Tags: visual-studio, google-drive-api, assemblies

Here is our question: How can recompile Google drive api sdk in dotnet?
=> We didn't find the source code.
=> In the binary package, there a single source file not shipped with a project and we don't know what to do with it.

**Reason of the question:**

In dotnet, we're unable to use the latest Google Drive api dll downloaded from Google: Google.Apis.Drive.v2

We are getting compilation errors like:

> Warning 10
>   The primary reference "Google.Apis.Drive.v2" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Google.Apis.Drive.v2" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

**Cause:**
This is because we are in Visual Studio 2010 with dotnet framework 4.0.
Apparently Google.Apis.Drive.v2 is compiled with dependencies to framework 4.5.

We cannot upgrade our project to Dotnet framework 4.5 because we have only Visual Studio 2010 and it would take months of testing upgrading to visual studio 2012.

**Troubleshooting**
We have tried to use Binding redirection in app.config files but it's not working with Class library projects that reference assemblies that need redirection (here Google.Apis.Drive.v2). 
For information, binding redirection was working fine if we changed the project to console application but failed when we switched back to class library.

@Google support: 
- Where do we download the source code of Google Drive api dll and how do we build it?
- Do you plan to ship a library for dotnet 4.0 because forcing 4.5 will block a lot of companies?

Comment: I think "months of testing" is overstating the case. You can install VS 2012 side-by-side with VS 2010, and update only the project that needs Google.Apis.Drive.v2 (plus projects that reference it) to .NET 4.5. You will almost certainly not have to make a single code change.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the source code for older versions (that compiled with .NET 3.5) at: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Services/?repo=samples&name=1.3.0-beta ([Google Drive](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Services/Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs?repo=samples&name=1.3.0-beta) in particular - it doesn't seem to exist in the main set).

I'm having trouble interacting with the source repository with Mercurial, but I was able to directly download the CS file and compile it in my own project. I'll edit if I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the code from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/

Comment: wrong link. Source code of Google drive api is not available in this link.

Comment: It's been generated by this project. You need to generate the source code and then build.

Comment: Looks very bad. The project is massively using Async which is new to dotnet 4.5. We have only a small piece of code in one project that needs Google Drive API. This will force to upgrade 7 computers to Visual studio 2012 and to convert more than 50 projects for use with Visual studio 2012. GOOGLE: YOUR ARE DOING THIS BAD BAD BAD. You shouldn't force your customers to perform 100 days of upgrade and testing just to use a small api in a corner. I would have a lot lot lot of things to say regarding their apis and documentations which is a calamity.

Comment: Not talking about Google docs api which permitted to do everything but are limited to 10 000 calls per day and it's replacement Google drive sdk which is a functional regression because we can't manipulate permissions with it (we only retrieve beautiful useless display names). Not talking about the nightmare for finding working samples for oauth for each apis. Not talking about the multiple different apis doing the same things with undocumented and blocking limitations in each of them.

Comment: I've worked 15 years at Lotus/IBM and Microsoft working on the source code of many many products. Google is a still a young company, their API set is a disaster. I feel it needs a strong program manager behind each SDK. If Google comes here, please escalate my comment. Seriously, your different sdk are bad.

Comment: Working with the Drive SDK as well the documentation is all over the place, sample projects state they work with .Net 3.5 and above but they don't, etc.

Comment: upvoting since it looks like the vent is aimed at google, not the answer itself.

Comment: Nope; I downvoted because he pointed to the main code repository, which does not support .NET 3.5.