# Does Google Drive API for VB Net works with net framework 3.5?

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, .net-3.5

I did some applications with Google Drive API and VB Net and works fine with net framework 4 but now I need to do it with net framework 3.5 does anybody knows if its going to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer here:

[How to recompile Google Drive API sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831223/how-to-recompile-google-drive-api-sdk)

They were able to compile the API with .net framework 3.5.